# PHP remove URL from string if URL contains specific letters

Tags: php, preg-match, strpos

I have a string and would like to remove any URLs that are image URLs, ex. contain a .jpg ending.

I am able to extract and separate the image URL from a string with preg_match_all and strpos, but now I need to "remove" the displayed image URL from the string itself (so that I can treat the image separately from the string)

```
preg_match_all('#\bhttps?://[^,\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^,[:punct:]\s]|/))#', $string, $match);

foreach ($match[0] as $link){
   $strpos = strpos($link, '.jpg');
   if ($strpos !== false){
       echo $link;
       break;   
   }
}
```

Input

```
$string = 'This is a string with a URL http://google.com and an image URL http://website.com/image.jpg';
```

Desired Output:

```
$string 'This is the string with a URL http://google.com and an image URL';
$image = '<img src="http://website.com/image.jpg"/>';
```

Comment: Str_replace the url with ''

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String replacement on match could do this one for you

```
<?php

preg_match_all('#\bhttps?://[^,\s()<>]+(?:\(\w+\)|([^,[:punct:]\s]|/))#', $string, $match);

foreach ($match[0] as $link){
   if (strpos($link, '.jpg') !== false){
       //Format the image url to an image element
       $image = '<img src="'.$link.'" />';

       //To substitute the image into the string
       echo str_replace($link, $image, $string);
       //To remove the link from original text: 
       echo str_replace($link, '', $string);

       break;   
   }
}
```

Hope this helps.

---

EDIT:

Remove unenecessary variable use for you, no need for the storage of the strpos result in the example above.

EDIT 2: Fixed syntax error with $link string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use til method to check string, 
   $list = what you want to check
   $endOfString = what you look for

```
function endsWith($list, $endOfString)
{
    $length = strlen($endOfString);
    if ($length == 0) {
        return true;
    }

    return (substr($list, -$length) === $endOfString);
}
```